# Cucumber can't find installed gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, cucumber

environment/cucumber.rb:

```
...
# gem dependencies
config.gem 'cucumber-rails',   :lib => false, :version => '>=0.3.0' unless File.directory?(File.join(Rails.root, 'vend
config.gem 'database_cleaner', :lib => false, :version => '>=0.5.0' unless File.directory?(File.join(Rails.root, 'vend
config.gem 'webrat',           :lib => false, :version => '>=0.7.0' unless File.directory?(File.join(Rails.root, 'vend

config.gem 'spork',            :lib => false, :version => '>=0.7.5' unless File.directory?(File.join(Rails.root, 'vend

config.gem 'factory_girl', :source => 'http://gemcutter.org'
config.gem 'selenium-client', :lib => false
config.gem 'Selenium', :lib => false
config.gem 'rspec', :lib => 'spec'
config.gem 'rspec-rails', :lib => 'spec/rails'
config.gem 'test-unit', :lib => false
```

Running cucumber gives missing gems error:

```
artem:~/projects/food4feed (master)$ cucumber
...
no such file to load -- Selenium
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/polyglot-0.3.0/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/rspec-rails-1.3.2/lib/spec/rails.rb:13:in `<top (required)>'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/polyglot-0.3.0/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/polyglot-0.3.0/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:158:in `require'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/gem_dependency.rb:208:in `load'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `block in load_gems'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `each'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:307:in `load_gems'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:169:in `process'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/home/artem/projects/food4feed/config/environment.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/polyglot-0.3.0/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/polyglot-0.3.0/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/home/artem/projects/food4feed/features/support/env.rb:12:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/spork-0.8.1/lib/spork.rb:23:in `prefork'
/home/artem/projects/food4feed/features/support/env.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/polyglot-0.3.0/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/polyglot-0.3.0/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/cucumber-0.6.3/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:124:in `load_code_file'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/cucumber-0.6.3/lib/cucumber/step_mother.rb:85:in `load_code_file'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/cucumber-0.6.3/lib/cucumber/step_mother.rb:77:in `block in load_code_files'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/cucumber-0.6.3/lib/cucumber/step_mother.rb:76:in `each'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/cucumber-0.6.3/lib/cucumber/step_mother.rb:76:in `load_code_files'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/cucumber-0.6.3/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:48:in `execute!'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/cucumber-0.6.3/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/gems/cucumber-0.6.3/bin/cucumber:8:in `<top (required)>'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
/home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/cucumber:19:in `<main>'
Missing these required gems:
  selenium-client
  Selenium
  rspec-rails

You're running:
  ruby 1.9.1.378 at /home/artem/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.1-p378/bin/ruby
  rubygems 1.3.5 at /home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378, /home/artem/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.1-p378%global
```

All gems are obviously there:

```
artem:~/projects/food4feed (master)$ gem list | egrep "elenium|rspec|test-unit"
rspec (1.3.0)
rspec-rails (1.3.2)
Selenium (1.1.14)
selenium-client (1.2.18)
test-unit (2.0.7)
```

Even more confusing part is that it only complains about certain gems. `factory_girl` and `rspec` don't cause problems.

Any idea what is going on?

---

My environment:

- Rails 2.3.5
- cucumber (0.6.3)
- cucumber-rails (0.3.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it (with the help of [aslakhellesoy](http://github.com/aslakhellesoy), thanks!). When cucumber says `Missing these required gems` it may also mean `Can't load these required gems`. Which adds the whole spectrum of possible errors.

In this case, gems names (apart from rspec-rails) didn't match corresponding library files to require. For instance, there should have been `:lib => 'selenium'` added to `config.gem 'selenium-client'`.

As for rspec-rails, it was failing to load because of the wrong version of test-unit: `Gem::LoadError: RubyGem version error: test-unit(2.0.7 not = 1.2.3)`. It would have helped a lot if cucumber reported this error in the first place (I got it from requiring rspec-rails from console).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have require 'test-unit' somewhere in your config/environment.rb or features/support/env.rb file?

If you do, that's wrong. The test-unit gem doesn't have a test-unit.rb file, so require 'test-unit' will always fail. Try to remove the require line, or at least try to require the correct file:

require 'test/unit'

I'm not sure why you're trying to explicitly load test-unit anyway.

Comment: `test-unit` is a dependency for one of the above gems. It is there only for `rake gems:install RAILS_ENV=cucumber` to install it.

Comment: CORRECTION!! CORRECTION!! `test-unit` doesn't actually cause problems, since it is `:lib => false`. My fault, I think I copied the wrong stack trace in the first place (corrected). However, it does not change the question.

Comment: You actually pointed to the right direction. Apart from rspec-rails, it was all about gem/library name mismatch. Thanks!